# Yet another "what's wrong with this question" question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've been trying to help the guy who asked this:

[Can course of the moving vehicle determine if the vehicle is moving left or right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822176/can-course-of-the-moving-vehicle-determine-if-the-vehicle-is-moving-left-or-righ)

And after rereading the `help` I can't think what to tell him he needs to fix.  What am I missing?

He's asking how to tell if the vehicle is turning.  He has a way to get a direction.  I want to tell him all he needs is to add a little math.  It's a just a derivative.

The hold claims his question is to broad.  It seems very exact to me if you trust him to really be asking what he is asking.  Is he required to explain why he want's to know this?

I've already given up on the hold but I would appreciate it if someone could make the problem clear to me.

Comment: The only interaction the OP has made is a single comment. He/she has not edited their post or done anything else. I'm sort of thinking you're putting in more effort than the OP.

Comment: And based on your comments from the post, I would agree that the question is "too broad". The OP can narrow it down by providing what they have done so far.

Comment: Well yes I am.  What's wrong with that?  Do you mean how I hedge my answer with if's?  I do that to everyone.  Gives me a chance to demonstrate what I think you mean.  Anyway, exactly what are you wanting to see narrowed down?  It's just a derivative.

Comment: @gunr2171 You actually can see what he's done so far.  His only other questions are about this GPS project.  And reading them doesn't help at all.  I'm glad he didn't drag all of that into this question.  Really, what would you have him add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> 1. Questions that *lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Describe your problem in more detail or include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.
> 2. […]
> 3. Questions asking for code must *demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.* Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

I'd say that the question fails to be a good Stack Overflow question, mostly due to #3.

Maybe would be appropriate for Programmers SE?

Comment: "I need to know if CLLocationDirection (course of the GPS) is the way to determine..." He didn't ask for code.  He asked if he was on the right track.

Comment: Wouldn't Programmers SE kick it back to SO saying it's an implementation issue?

Comment: @CandiedOrange it depends on how its phrased. It *could* be a reasonable P.SE question with some work.  The abstract "given a set of points, how can you determine if the entity is bearing to the left or right" with the associated "this is what I'm thinking, and it isn't working" - however, the question when slimmed down to "I need to know if CLLocationDirection (course of the GPS) is the way to determine whether the moving vehicle is turning left or right or going straight? If so, how?" doesn't give enough information to determine what the issue is (unclear / too broad).

Comment: @CandiedOrange see also [Why is research important?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important) - the issues in that meta post would need to be resolved before it would be a good question for P.SE.

Answer (score 5):

As you know that question has been reopened.

<strike>However I would express my disappointment that you haven't actually tendered an answer yet, there's just a conversation going on in the comments.</strike>

**This conversation indicates that maybe 0x7FFFFFFF ♦ took the right action when he closed it as too broad.**

After three edits over the space of 20 hours there is still not enough information to make it a good question. Conversations in the comments section are discouraged - the site isn't a discussion forum and too much information can get lost in the noise of the comments.

Comment: I have answered it.  I certainly didn't comment once it was reopened.  It took time because I discovered a nasty corner case and was taking some time to do it right.  I had given up on the hold anyway so wasn't expecting it to change.  Conversation indicates the hold kept me from answering it sooner if anything.  If you still want to put it on hold will you please say exactly what needs to be added to the question before you do?  Just chanting "too broad" doesn't teach anyone anything.